# Allow only YouTube videos and block other videos

Tags: firewalls, video

I have a MikroTik router. I want to allow only Youtube videos and block all other videos. I tried to write an extended ACL but I really have no idea. Maybe allow only Youtube videos source URL and block other URLs? Can you guys help me?

Comment: This is going to be an incredibly difficult, if not impossible task to accomplish. Why would you like to do that?

Comment: Let me guess: you want to block porn? If so, there are many, many other better ways to do that.

Comment: There's porn on YouTube anyways, so this isn't a very good way to stop people from looking at it.

Comment: @user yes, but Google has controls to block that.

Comment: @schroeder If the question author is concerned about blocking sites at the router level then I'm pretty sure that the network users can bypass local restrictions.

Comment: @user but not at the Google Account level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Far As I know, you have 3 choices:

1. You can use URL filtering by allowing "youtube" or any URLs in the [**MikroTik firewall**](https://monovm.com/blog/block-url-on-mikrotik/) in the layer7 protocol field and deny the other specifically or deny all as that link shows.
2. You can use content filtering to block [**Adult WebSites**](https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=45319) in your MikroTik.
3. You can use proxy servers such as Squid for URL filtering.

There is also another solution that may help you, you can monitor your network **[NetFlow Traffic](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Traffic_Flow)** and find out what is exactly going on, on your network and based on that you can provide a good and suitable solution for issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can read a detailed article at the squid-cache wiki:
https://wiki.squid-cache.org/EliezerCroitoru/Drafts/YouTubeFiltering

Technically you will need to use the next REGEX to block or allow a specific video.
To define a policy you will need to use some wildcard match at the end of the policy in the Proxy/firewall.

```
(^|.*\.)youtube\.com/embed/##VID##
(^|.*\.)youtube\.com/watch\?v=##VID##
(^|.*\.)ytimg\.com/.*/##VID##/
(^|.*\.)youtu\.be/.*##VID##.*
```